# Standard Input and Output operations in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stdout, stdin

What is the approach for using standard i/o in flutter? I've tried the following code but there is no render and build gets stuck.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
 stdout.writeln("Enter value");
 String str = stdin.readLineSync();
// user inputs value
 print(str);
}
```

The documentation says

```
> To read text synchronously from the command line (the program blocks
> waiting for user to type information):

String inputText = stdin.readLineSync();
```

But how to appropriately input values? Because flutter run doesn't let me input values.

Comment: Can be more specific? I am quite not to understand the question.

Comment: What platform?  And are you wanting a Dart command-line tool (which would have nothing to do with Flutter)?

Comment: I'm using flutter command line tool. Using `flutter run` to start the flutter app. But flutter command line has it's own set of user input such as manual hot reloading. What I'm trying to achieve is to print value returned from stdin.readLineSync() which waits for user typed input and prints the value. I don't how to use dart:io package. I've found Stdin class @ api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin-class.html. Don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you're doing doesn't require you to use `Flutter`. You can run it using `Dart`. The thing is that `Flutter` is meant for application development for Android, iOS, Web and other such platforms. It isn't created for such applications that you desire.